# Couldnt find the correct rotation matrix

Tags: python, geometry, geolocation, rotation, point-clouds

i have 2d profiler lidar i want to georeferance it. However which rotation order i tried i couldnt able to find correct one. Where am doing wrong i dont understand.

i like to get pointcloud as the image below
[image]

but i am getting like this
[image]

there is a waving effect in the bump.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation
 
points =  np.loadtxt("eee.txt",delimiter=",") #np.load("points.npy") #
 

offsetssyaw = [45,135,225,315]
offsetsspithch = [45,135,225,315]

 
for yaw in offsetssyaw:
    for pitch in offsetsspithch:
        for dd in [4]:
            id = 0
            globalpoint = []
            for i in points:

                rotation_original = np.array([i[8]+179.71 , i[9]+pitch , i[10]+yaw])  # Rotation angles in degrees

                

                # Convert the rotation angles to a rotation matrix
                if dd == 1:
                    rotation_matrix = Rotation.from_euler('xyz', np.array([i[8]+179.71 , i[9]+pitch , i[10]+yaw]), degrees=True).as_matrix()
                if dd == 2:
                    rotation_matrix = Rotation.from_euler('xzy', np.array([i[8]+179.71 , i[10]+yaw, i[9]+pitch ]), degrees=True).as_matrix()
                if dd == 3:
                    rotation_matrix = Rotation.from_euler('yxz', np.array([i[9]+pitch ,i[8]+179.71 ,  i[10]+yaw]), degrees=True).as_matrix()
                if dd == 4:
                    rotation_matrix = Rotation.from_euler('yzx', np.array([ i[9]+pitch , i[10]+yaw,i[8]+179.71 ]), degrees=True).as_matrix()
                if dd == 5:
                    rotation_matrix = Rotation.from_euler('zxy', np.array([i[10]+yaw,i[8]+179.71 , i[9]+pitch  ]), degrees=True).as_matrix()
                if dd == 6:
                    rotation_matrix = Rotation.from_euler('zyx', np.array([i[10]+yaw , i[9]+pitch ,i[8]+179.71 ]), degrees=True).as_matrix()
                 

                # Perform the rotation on the point using the rotation matrix
                pointmatrix = np.dot(rotation_matrix, [i[5],i[6],i[7]])
                  

                inte1 = i[3]


            
                
                globalpoint.append([pointmatrix[0]+i[0] ,pointmatrix[1]+i[1] ,i[2]+pointmatrix[2] , inte1,id,i[4]])
       
                id += 1
                old = i[4]

            out = pd.DataFrame(globalpoint)
            out.to_csv(f"test/outPitch_{pitch}_yaw_{yaw}_order{dd}.txt")
```

i have tried this code. The only similar possibility is when pitch 315 and yaw 225 and the order is 4